# Prove that $\frac{1+ab}{1+a}+\frac{1+bc}{1+b}+\frac{1+ca}{1+c}\geq 3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, radicals, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have to prove that $$\frac{1+ab}{1+a}+\frac{1+bc}{1+b}+\frac{1+ca}{1+c}\geq 3 $$
is always true for real numbers $a, b, c>0$ with $abc=1$.

Using the AM-GM inequality I got as far as $$\frac{1+ab}{1+a}+\frac{1+bc}{1+b}+\frac{1+ca}{1+c}\geq \frac{b}{\sqrt[a+1]{b}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt[b+1]{c}}+\frac{a}{\sqrt[c+1]{a}}$$
but I do not yet know how to finish my proof from there (if this is helpful at all?!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{1+ab}{1+a}=\frac{abc+ab}{1+a}=ab\big(\frac{1+c}{1+a}\big)$. So what is $\big(\frac{1+ab}{1+a}\big)\big(\frac{1+bc}{1+b}\big)\big(\frac{1+ca}{1+c}\big)$?

Comment: this is a very good idea!

Comment: Thank you! It's an ingenious idea to first calculate the product of the three fractions instead of the sum - the rest of the solution is quite easy then.

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1+ab}{1+a}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}\frac{1+ab}{1+a}}=3\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}\frac{1+\frac{1}{c}}{1+a}}=$$
$$=3\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}\frac{1+c}{1+a}}=3.$$

Comment: I don't really see why $3\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}\frac{1+\frac{1}{c}}{1+a}}$ should be equal to $3\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}\frac{1+c}{1+a}}$. Could you explain that, please?

Comment: @mxian  $\sqrt[3]{\prod\limits_{cyc}\frac{1+\frac{1}{c}}{1+a}}=\sqrt[3]{\prod\limits_{cyc}\frac{1+c}{c(1+a)}}=\sqrt[3]{\prod\limits_{cyc}\frac{1+c}{1+a}}$ because $abc=1$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Now I see. Using Especially Lime's comment, we can see that $$\left(\frac{1+ab}{1+a}\right)\left(\frac{1+bc}{1+b}\right)\left(\frac{1+ca}{1+c}\right)=1.$$
Hence, we can set $$x:=\frac{1+ab}{1+a}, y:=\frac{1+bc}{1+b}$$ and our inequality becomes $$x+y+\frac{1}{xy}\geq 3$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{x+y+\frac{1}{xy}}{3}\geq 1.$$ But using the AM-GM inequality for three variables, we can see that $$\frac{x+y+\frac{1}{xy}}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{xy\cdot\frac{1}{xy}}=1,$$and our claim follows.